# Installing Python setuptools, returning import error

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to install setuptools 0.9.7 with Python 3.3.  I try to run "python setup.py", and also "python setup.py install" from a cmd window in a directory separate from my default python dir, and get back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5 in ?
    import textwrap
ImportError: No module named textwrap
```

...even though I checked \Lib\ and textwrap.py is there.  So then I copied textwrap.py to the directory I was trying to install setuptools from, and then get:

```
Traceback
  File "setup.py", line 5, in ?
    import textwrap
  File "textwrap.py", line 404
    yield (prefix + line if predicate(line) else line)
SyntaxError
```

...even though I can import `textwrap.py` just fine while working in the default Python directory.  So I'm at a loss.  I should say that I've tried to install two other modules and have received similar import errors, I was hoping setuptools would fix that.  Any ideas?

Comment: What does `python -V` tell you the version is you are running?

Comment: Ah, it says python 2.2.  There is an older version installed on this (quite old) machine.

Comment: Make sure you use the right Python version. :-) `python3` should work on many distributions.

Comment: I would suggest sticking by the default `python2.7`.

Comment: From the install directory I try to run python3 setup.py, and I'm getting "'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: Check your installation. Are you sure you have Python 3.3 installed? You might need to provide the full path to the python3 command...